# SQL - How to reference outerquery new column in subquery

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'd like to create a new variable in an outerquery, and then manipulate this new variable in a subquery.

However, when referencing the new column in the subquery, I receive an error that `no such column exists`

Code:

```
dbGetQuery(db, 
  "SELECT id, var1/var2 AS new_var, (SELECT SUM(new_var) AS summed_var
    FROM table 
    GROUP BY id) 
  FROM table")
```

In this above code, the issue is that `new_var` doesn't get passed to the subquery. How can I pass the newly defined column, `new_var` to the subquery?

EDIT: switching the inner query/outer query still doesn't work:

```
dbGetQuery(db, 
  "SELECT SUM(new_var) AS summed_var (SELECT id, var1/var2 AS new_var
    FROM table)
  FROM table
  GROUP BY id")
```

EDIT 2: The data is structured as below. Each row is an observation for an `id`. I would like to generate a ratio, `new_var = var1/var2` for each line.  Then, I would like to sum the ratio `new_var` for each id.
In the toy data, for example, the summed ratio for Sally would be `3/4 + 7/8`.

My challenge was using `GROUP BY` with SQL. I was unsure how to perform `GROUP BY id` after generating the `new_var` on a line-by-line basis.

```
id       var1     var2    new_var
sally     3        4         3/4
susan     5        6         5/6
sally     7        8         7/8
tom       9        10        9/10
```

Comment: What RDMBS are you using?

Comment: I'm using sqlite, if that answers the question

Comment: You can't do that. Conceptually, the outer query doesn't start until after the subquery is completed.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Ah, thanks for the clarification. If I switch the query such that the ```group by``` is performed in the outerquery on ```new_var```, while ```new_var``` is defined in the inner query, this still doesn't work

Comment: It is not clear what we are trying to achieve by this. 1. **table** seems to be a reserved  word in Sqlite, use a different name. 2. your first query uses a subquery as a column expression, but that subquery  can return multiple rows (**group by Id** implies one row per id). 3. you can't pass an alias (new_var) to a subquery (at least it appears so for SqLite); if you give different aliases to each table references, you can refer to the outer table variables.

Comment: , like:
SELECT id, var1/var2 AS new_var, 
   (SELECT SUM(tbl1.var1/tbl1.var2) AS summed_var
    FROM tble tbl2
    where tbl2.id=tbl1.id) as SomeDeriveColumn 
  FROM tble tbl1

But this is a trivial example because it wouldn't require a subquery.

Comment: please explain why you thought using a subquery would solve your problem (what was your problem)?

Comment: @userMT thank you for the comments. I'm new to SQL :) and was trying to complete a calculation for each row in the data, and then sum that variable for each id in the date. I read in other posts that a subquery was the solution for this challenge

Comment: Try posting your actual data, and expected result. We need to understand your data: for each id do you have more than one record (same or different var1/var2 values)?

Why wouldn't  a simple **select id, sum(var1/var2) as rslt from Tble group by id** do? This one calculates var1/var2 for each row, and then sums them for each id.

Comment: @userMT, thank you for the followup! Just edited the question to answer your point

Comment: Why did you accept an answer that returns wrong results: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=c2f407701ec89d707cb82b0a596ab874 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you actually want to show the result but not the 'equation 3/4' the following should do what you want:

```
select 
    id
  , sum(var1/var2) as summed_var 
from Tble 
group by id
```

All expressions other than involving aggregation results (i.e. those standing alone, or inside aggregation functions like SUM, COUNT, etc) are evaluated for each row( which means that var1/var2 is calculated for each row), then the aggregation (SUM) is performed for each group formed by Id (GROUP BY Id)

Is this what you seek?

Answer (score 0):

Use `SUM()` window function:

```
SELECT *,
       ROUND(1.0 * var1 / var2, 2) new_var,
       ROUND(SUM(1.0 * var1 / var2) OVER (PARTITION BY id), 2) summed
FROM tablename;
```

or:

```
SELECT *,
       ROUND(1.0 * var1 / var2, 2) new_var,
       ROUND(1.0 * SUM(var1) OVER (PARTITION BY id) / SUM(var2) OVER (PARTITION BY id), 2) summed
FROM tablename;
```

or if you want the results as text:

```
SELECT *,
       var1 || '/' || var2 new_var,
       SUM(var1) OVER (PARTITION BY id) || '/' || SUM(var2) OVER (PARTITION BY id) summed
FROM tablename;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=64c4a49f7ae05f2bfd3e8b7190783444).